# How to check the folders relationship toeach other in Rally using Java API

Tags: java, parent-child, rally

I am trying to use the `"Parent"` attribute of a folder inside the `"QueryFilter"` as shown:

```
myFolder.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("TestFolder.Name", "=", foldername)
    .and(new QueryFilter("Parent", "=", ??????)));
```

I am trying to check whether this folder is a subfolder of another folder.

I dont know what to put instead of `??????`.

UPDATE: 
I am using following code but its throwing a nullpointer exception. I am trying to query for a parent folder, so I am putting Parent as null. I dont know if I should get nullpointer exception. If yes, how should I handle it?

QueryRequest parent1 = new QueryRequest("TestFolder");

parent1.setFetch(new Fetch("Name","Project"));

parent1.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("name", "=", foldername).and(new 
QueryFilter("Parent", "=", null)).and(new QueryFilter("Project", "=", proj_ref)));

QueryResponse parent2 = batman.query(parent1);

parent_ref = parent2.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString();

System.out.println("Parent ref: "+parent_ref);

System.out.println("Parent folder already exists.");

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rally's WSAPI fields that reference another object (like Parent) can be referred to using a ref url.

```
//no parent
new QueryFilter("Parent", "=", null);

//specific parent 
new QueryFilter("Parent", "=", "/testfolder/12345");
```

Comment: I tried using new QueryFilter("Parent", "=", null); for a testfolder which is not supposed to have any parent. Its throwing me a null pointer exception which I am unable to handle.

Comment: You're right- this is a bug that I'll make sure is fixed for the 1.0.5 release.  Until then make null a string: new QueryFilter("Parent", "=", "null");

Comment: Ok. but would it fail my current application once you include this bug fix in the 1.0.5 update? I mean if I keep using 1.0.4 and do not upgrade to 1.0.5 for this particular application for sometime, would my application throw exception? Cuz I am putting this application on a server which would run it everyday. I don't want the application to fail, if possible. I actually do not know how these bug fixes affects the codes written with older api versions. Thanks.

Comment: "null" will continue to work in 1.0.5.  We try very hard to not break backwards compatibility unless absolutely necessary when releasing a new version.